# space at beginning of line in .gitignore seems to get the line ignored

Tags: git, gitignore

The only difference between the `.gitignore` is a space at the beginning of a line, and it seems to make the line ignored. Why is the result different. I add the space for alignment.

**Git folder tree structure**:

```
.
└── d1
    ├── d11
    │   ├── f1
    │   └── f2
    ├── d12
    │   ├── f1
    │   └── f2
    └── f1
```

First **.gitignore**:

```
/*
!d1
d1/*
!/d1/d11
```

First stageable files:

```
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   d1/d11/f1
        new file:   d1/d11/f2
```

Second **.gitignore**: (notice the difference in the third rule)

```
/*
!d1
 d1/*
!/d1/d11
```

Second stageable files:

```
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   d1/d11/f1
        new file:   d1/d11/f2
        new file:   d1/d12/f1
        new file:   d1/d12/f2
        new file:   d1/f1
```

[Here is the image of my execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ095.png) I expect the outcome should be the same.

The wrong intuition may come from this rule which says nothing about beginning space. I did see the word trailing though.

```
Trailing spaces are ignored unless they are quoted with backslash ("\").
```

Comment: "I expect the outcome should be the same." Why do you expect that? Is it a documented rule, or did you just make it up in your head?

Comment: I mean a space at the beginning should make no difference

Comment: I guess git does not act like what I think it is. But how is it different. Is git taking the space as part of the path name?

Comment: Note that *trailing* spaces are usually not visible in an editor, but *leading* spaces are pretty clear (it's a good idea to use a fixed-width font when editing this kind of file, too, so you can see *how many* spaces there are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `d1/*` and  `d1/*` is that the first ignores everything under the folder named `d1` and the second ignores everything under the `' d1'` folder.

The reasoning behind this is that **folders can start with blank spaces**.

So those two `.gitignore` files are matching different folders. Hence why the second one includes everything under `d1` folder.